# For a certain problem if I have a O(f1(m,n)) algorithm and a O(f2(m,n)) algorithm, can I have a O(min(f1(m,n),f2(m,n))) algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Actually, I have this question because of clrs 14.3.4 https://walkccc.me/CLRS/Chap14/14.3/ I know how to prove O(N)for traversal and O(k*logN) for delete every time. so how to prove there exists O(min(N,k*logN)) becomes a question. (I asked it in [How to prove the time complexity of query in interval tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77414782/how-to-prove-the-time-complexity-of-query-in-interval-tree))

Assert this is correct, can any algorithms  having  a O(f1(m,n))  and a O(f2(m,n)) solution have a O(min(f1(m,n),f2(m,n))) solution(for m,n not known before execution).

Comment: Note: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for such questions.

Comment: I have two remarks. (1) "Traversal" and "delete" are two different problems. I'm not sure how you would combine an algorithm for traversal with an algorithm for delete. (2) I urge you to use precise vocabulary and make a distinction between the words "problem" and "algorithm". You can have several different algorithms to solve the same problem; and you can combine two algorithms to make a new algorithm; a problem has a solution; a problem is solved by an algorithm; an algorithm doesn't "have a O(f1(m,n)) solution".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.
If you have a O(f1(m,n)) and a O(f2(m,n)) solution, you could
execute each of the solutions in pseudo-parallel (time-sliceing) and stop when one of them found the solution.

This way you get an O(min(f1(m,n),f2(m,n))) algorithm.

This is 2 times slower than performing the algorithm that found the solution first alone but that makes no difference according to the O-Notation (because 2 is only a constant factor).

Comment: I'm not convinced. If both solutions don't modify the input, then sure. But what if they do? How do you run both if their modifications conflict and mess each other up? You could try duplicating the input beforehand, but that might already exceed the desired time complexity. So what do you do? I think it's at least not trivial and needs to be addressed. (Thought provoked by Stef's comment.)

Comment: As an example, consider the problem of getting an m×n×k array, having to make all A[i][j][0] equal, and one solution sets them all to 0 whereas the other sets them all to 1.

Comment: @KellyBundy you can use views into the input data that store updates separately from the input data. You can initialize these views in O(1) with a well-known trick (eg: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/23/initializing-an-array-in-constant-time). Obviously this can change the auxiliary space complexity, but that doesn't seem to be a constraint in the question.

Comment: You can also store undo information for each operation.  Then execute algo1 for 1 second, undo, execute algo2 for 1 second, undo, repeat for 2 secs, repeat for 4 secs, etc., until one of them completes.  Still O(min(T1,T2))